# Use VBA to automatically select multiple columns in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on this project in Excel that needs me to select a starting month and the pivot table gives out the data for the following 15 months.

My thinking is I could use VBA, but I don't know how it can know I'm looking for the information in the next 15 months..
[image: For instance, right now 1/1/2021 is selected, I'll need the pivot table to display information up to 3/1/2022 only]
For instance, right now 1/1/2021 is selected, I'll need the pivot table to display information up to 3/1/2022 only

Comment: Seeing the source data might help - and not as a picture

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly (how to make VBA update the range in the table), this should do the trick:

Go to VBA (Alt+F11 or from Developer Tab), right click on the "This Workbook" and select "View Code"[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rVqka.jpg)

Paste the below code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

'Insert name of worksheet with Pivot table in place of Sheet1
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B12").Value = Date 

End Sub
```

This will refresh the date every time the workbook is opened.

However to get 100% accurate answer, you would have to check how the Pivot table is edited with change in this field, you have to share the code to do this.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question of OP however. As you can see, there's a dropdown in B12 and the selected date wasn't the date of posting/"Today" either.